# OneDrive client fails to login, silently closes and reopens

Tags: microsoft-office-365, onedrive-for-business

To preface, there are GPOs in place for SharePoint library auto maps as well as some global OneDrive policy items such as auto sign-in.

I have this issue with at least 2 users, but essentially when the user attempts to sign in, nothing happens, and the user is not signed in. To expand on this:

1. User checks OneDrive in System Tray, icon is grey cloud with line thru it, not logged in. User chooses to Sign In on OneDrive app
2. User enters username and clicks Sign In
3. OneDrive closes, no errors. Icon disappears from System Tray.
4. A new OneDrive icon appears in the system tray for half a second, it is a blue cloud with a red line thru it, then disappears.
5. Another OneDrive icon returns to system tray this time a grey cloud with a line thru it, and OneDrive is not signed in. This icon stays visible.

Every time you attempt to sign in, this happens.

I have removed and reinstalled OneDrive, installed the lateset with the /AllUsers switch. I have done a OneDrive.exe /reset. I have rebooted the computer. I have removed all OneDrive registry keys between un/reinstall. I do not see any event log entries pertaining to OneDrive. I removed the Office cached credentials, there were no other cached credentials present. The user is licensed (Bus. Std.) and is enabled and unlocked in 365.

Comment: Open a support case in your Office 365 tenant. That's probably the best way to find the solution at this point. Office 365 support is free.